# Calling a constructor without creating object

Tags: c++, object, constructor

What exactly is happening in the code below.

```
#include<iostream.h>

class Demo
{
    public :

    Demo()
    {
        cout<<"\nIn Demo const";
    }
    ~Demo()
    {
        cout<<"\nin demo dest";
    }
};

void main() {
    Demo();
}
```

`Demo()` simply calls the constructor and destructor. Is a object being created in this process? And thus is the memory being allocated?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're not explicitly calling the constructor, instead this code creates a temporary unnamed object with type `Demo`, which is destroyed immediately after `;`.

Yes, memory is allocated (automatically, on the stack) for this temp object and it's freed (again automatically) after `;`. Meanwhile, the constructor and destructor are called, as expected.

Comment: Begin picky: In this example, the object does not have any members and no inheritance is involved. Therefore the object does not require any space on the stack. At least, any sane compiler will optimize this to a plain function call.

Comment: @PhilippAumayr - do you mean, that  `sizeof(Demo)` is zero (`0`) ?

Comment: @PhilippAumayr at least if no vtable is created (rtti disabled)

Comment: @KirilKorov: No, `sizeof` can never be zero.  But most compilers will not actually use any storage for the temporary dataless object, which is fine by the "as-if" rule.

Comment: @aschepler - I know this about the `sizeof`, I just thought @PhilippAumayr means it, that's why I asked :)

Comment: I'd add that (1) the allocation (very likely) doesn't consume any CPU time since no real actions are performed during allocation/deallocation (the compiler simply reserve 1 byte of memory in the stack frame) and (2) theoretically even the allocation (memory reservation) might be optimized out due to "as if rule"

Comment: @KirilKirov thanks for the info about sizeof, didn't know that.

Comment: This is right, but it's even more strange: Syntactically, ___you cannot call constructors___ yourself. You can only create objects, and upon their creation the constructors will automatically get invoked.

Comment: @KirilKirov sizeof can be zero in one case : on forward declared type name. This may be useful with template programming.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, memory is allocated but on the stack, and `Demo()` is creating a temporary object which gets destructed automatically.