# Invoking constructor without an object

Tags: c++, class, c++11

I forgot to add the object name in front of class name, but the code still compiled and constructor got invoked. I am really bamboozled what actually happened here. Does not it mean that we can invoke the constructor without creating an object?

My code :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class PrintJobs
{
    private:
        int nPages;
        static int nTrayPages;
        static int nJobs;

    public:
        PrintJobs(int np) : nPages(np)
        {
            nJobs++;
            cout << "Printing " <<  nPages <<"pages" << endl;
        }
        ~PrintJobs()
        {
            --nJobs;
        }

        static int getJobs()
        {
            return nJobs;
        }

        static int checkPages()
        {
            return nTrayPages;
        }

        static void loadPages(int n)
        {
            nTrayPages += n ;
        }

};

int PrintJobs::nTrayPages = 500 ;
int PrintJobs::nJobs = 0 ;

int main()
{
    cout << "Jobs  " << PrintJobs::getJobs() << "\n" ;
    cout << "Pages " << PrintJobs::checkPages() << "\n";

    PrintJobs(10); /// This is the line I am confused about.

    cout << "Jobs  " << PrintJobs::getJobs() << "\n" ;
    cout << "Pages " << PrintJobs::checkPages() << "\n";
    {
        PrintJobs p(30) , p2(20);
        cout << "Jobs  " << PrintJobs::getJobs() << "\n" ;
            cout << "Pages " << PrintJobs::checkPages() << "\n";
            PrintJobs::loadPages(100);

    }

    cout << "Jobs  " << PrintJobs::getJobs() << "\n" ;
    cout << "Pages " << PrintJobs::checkPages() << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Jobs  0
Pages 500
Printing 10pages
Jobs  0
Pages 500
Printing 30pages
Printing 20pages
Jobs  2
Pages 500
Jobs  0
Pages 600
```

Comment: What makes you think that there isn't an object?

Comment: You have created a _temporary_.  You can create values without giving them names.  It's rather fundamental to the language.

Comment: PrintJobs(10) , where did create an object ? I would have created an object if I would have written as PrintJobs x or something .Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: `PrintJobs x(10)` creates an object **and** gives it a name.  `PrintJobs(10)` just removes the name.  Research what _a temporary_ is.

Comment: Why the downvotes guys , its a proud , independent ,self reliant question

Comment: You did invoke the constructor, namely this one: `PrintJobs(int np)`.

Comment: Because of the picture of your terninal. No one wants to see pictures of terminals.

Comment: @Kevin If you are talking about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26336825/c-constructor-without-parameter-name) it is not at all the same question.

Comment: @NathanOliver [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892035/calling-a-constructor-without-creating-object) was the first result for me.

Comment: @Kevin Cool.  Thanks.  That wasn't my first result